# Why would an animal have facial doors?

Tags: fantasy-races, dragons, underwater

The facial door is a unique structure. They are surrounded on both sides by a row of tusks, and are composed of a pair of plates, which are supported by a bony core that is jointed to the skull, and can be opened or closed by the facial muscles. They are situated on the dorsal side of the face, just behind the nose. This feature is found on a large, semiaquatic predator

What could be the purpose of the facial doors?

[image]

Comment: What's the difference, apart from semantic, between your "facial door" and a "mouth"?

Comment: So like the plates of the quiet place monster?

Comment: I wondered at first why the eyes and nose are aligned horizontally instead of vertically like humans, but then I put myself the image of a crocodile. Makes more sense now :p.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Protecting delicate sensory organs**

Your creature has some sort of organ that only functions in a specific environment or needs to be protected from something like the rigors of combat and thus needs to be protected conditionally.

For example, maybe it has extremely delicate chemical receptors behind its "doors" that only work underwater and are damaged when exposed to air. Because it takes a long time to grow them and they are critical to the creature's hunting habits, it has evolved these "doors" which enable them to carry a pocket of water with them to protect the organs when on land and expose them underwater for maximum sensory range. In the opposite direction, the "door" could act as a muffler for extremely sensitive ears: The "door" is open on land to allow the creature to hear with extreme fidelity, but because the ears are so sensitive and water conducts sound so well, exposing this ear underwater directly would cause it to overload and become damaged (less sensitive). The creature therefore closes this door, reducing the efficacy of the ear but protecting it from damage.

Alternatively, your creature uses the bony tusks on its head for combat purposes and wants to protect the delicate organs inside when not in use. For example, maybe it has some electro-perceptive organs inside that let it locate prey from a long range, but the sensory organ is delicate and by closing the "door" the creature protects this organ when it goes for the kill.

Answer (score 1):

**They are blowholes.**

[image: blowholes]

http://whaleopedia.org/evolution-of-whales/

Midway between the snout and the eyes is a fine place for a blowhole.  Ancestors of the whale had their breathing passages sited there.   Your predator is an air breather, and can breathe while floating motionless in the water, face and eyes submerged.  The "facial door" on the dorsal face is in the air and so this creature can breathe without raising its head for a breath.  It can close the blowhole when it goes underwater.